# How to set options in ng2-date-picker?

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I'm using angular 2 date picker ng2-date-picker. Here i don't know how to set minDate, maxDate, dateFormat and other options. Please help me on this.

code:

```html
<dp-date-picker></dp-date-picker>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a config object inside the component.ts as follows,

```
 constructor() {}
  config = {
    firstDayOfWeek: 'su',
    monthFormat: 'MMM, YYYY',
    disableKeypress: false,
    allowMultiSelect: false,
    closeOnSelect: undefined,
    closeOnSelectDelay: 100,
    onOpenDelay: 0,
    weekDayFormat: 'ddd',
    appendTo: document.body,
    drops: 'down',
    opens: 'right',
    showNearMonthDays: true,
    showWeekNumbers: false,
    enableMonthSelector: true,
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
    yearFormat: 'YYYY',
    showGoToCurrent: true,
    dayBtnFormat: 'DD',
    monthBtnFormat: 'MMM',
    hours12Format: 'hh',
    hours24Format: 'HH',
    meridiemFormat: 'A',
    minutesFormat: 'mm',
    minutesInterval: 1,
    secondsFormat: 'ss',
    secondsInterval: 1,
    showSeconds: false,
    showTwentyFourHours: true,
    timeSeparator: ':',
    multipleYearsNavigateBy: 10,
    showMultipleYearsNavigation: false,
    locale: 'zh-cn',
    // min:'2017-08-29 15:50',
    // minTime:'2017-08-29 15:50'
  };
```

and refer in the component as,

```
 <dp-date-picker  theme="dp-material" [(ngModel)]="value" mode='daytime' [config]='config'
     (ngModelChange)="validatorsChanged()"
      [placeholder]="placeholder" [mode]='mode' #datePicker> 
  </dp-date-picker>
```

Comment: Thanks lot Sajeetharan :). But still i don't know the how to disable future date.

Comment: to disable array of dates check this https://github.com/vlio20/angular-datepicker/issues/187

Comment: please is there any way to set the date format to DD-MM-YYYY, i did put it in the config object and it didn't work, the date format cannot be parsed

Comment: anyone know how to achieve datetime picker with same package. i've configured to get date and time by setting `closeOnSelect: true,`. but couldn't get the date and time. kindly someone provide example for this . @Sajeetharan can you pls help me on this

Answer (score 2):

for use:

install: `npm i ng2-date-picker`

1- app.component.html

```
<dp-date-picker dir="rtl" theme="dp-material" placeholder="۱۳۹۸/۱۰/۰۸" required="true"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" [config]="datePickerConfig" minDate="07/11/2020">
 </dp-date-picker>
```

2-  app.component.ts

```
datePickerConfig = {
    drops: 'up',
    format: 'YY/M/D'
  }
```

3-  AppComponetModule .ts

```
import { DpDatePickerModule } from 'ng2-jalali-date-picker';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DpDatePickerModule
  ],
})
```

And you can use the website:   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker

Comment: could not found "dp-material" theme

Comment: And you can use the website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker